# What is the use of coordinationType in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am new to JPA, I started JPA applications. While doing I found

```
@Cache(coordinationType=CacheCoordinationType.INVALIDATE_CHANGED_OBJECTS)
```

And more Types in  coordination. I didn't under stand the use of coordinationType in JPA. Can anyone tell me about that When to use  and  What coordination type to use.

Comment: Its not a JPA feature. Its a feature from eclipselink implementation. Infos: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_cache.htm

Comment: @pL4Gu33 thank you. I go through that one but I didn't find the answer. They given Set this attribute to the cache coordination mode. Then here what is coordination  mode.

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/solutions/scaling002.htm --> Scroll down to "Using Cache Coordination"

Answer (score 6):

JPA 2.0 uses two caches: The first one is your entity manager. It was available with JPA 1.0 and caches its object during its lifetime. Since you should use entity manger for a single *unit of work*, this lifetime is usually rather short. JPA 2.0 introduced the second level cache, where object usually live much longer. While usually this gives an performance advantage, it may lead to cache inconsistencies, especially in multionode enviroments. `CacheCoordinationType` is an eclipselink extension to control cache replication. For portable applications you probably want to use the JPA cache API. Which strategy is best depends strongly on your applications need for consistency and performance. If you want maximum performance and you can live with some outdated answer, do not propagte changes, but limit the lifetinme of object in your cache. Otherwise notify about changes and watch out for to things:

1. In multinode you have to setup you cache replication correctly.
2. You have to take care of other applications that might change the data. This usually means disabling the cache for tables that may be changed from other applications.

Answer (score 0):

According to the CacheCoordinationType javadoc:

```
/** 
 * An enum that is used within the Cache annotation.
 * 
 * @see org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.Cache
 * @author Guy Pelletier
 * @since Oracle TopLink 11.1.1.0.0 
 */ 
public enum CacheCoordinationType {
    /**
     * Sends a list of changed objects including data about the changes. 
     * This data is merged into the receiving cache.
     */
    SEND_OBJECT_CHANGES,

    /**
     * Sends a list of the identities of the objects that have changed. The 
     * receiving cache invalidates the objects (rather than changing any of the 
     * data)
     */
    INVALIDATE_CHANGED_OBJECTS,

    /**
     * Same as SEND_OBJECT_CHANGES except it also includes any newly created 
     * objects from the transaction.
     */
    SEND_NEW_OBJECTS_WITH_CHANGES,

    /**
     * Does no cache coordination.
     */
    NONE
}
```

Here are some resourses that may help:
@Example 2-10 Using @Cache Annotation
https://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_cache.htm

Optimization #3 - Query Cache
http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-improve-jpa-performance-by-1825.html